# How do I view python modules? They are .so files and PyCharm does not recognize how to open them

Tags: python, module, .so

I want to read how some of the modules work. I thought they would be .py files which could teach me the inner workings of then. However when I import a module it says it is coming from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/math.cpython-36m-darwin.so

I went to the lib-dynload folder under external libraries in PyCharm but these module files are all '.so' files.

What is a .so file?

How can I view a .so file and learn about the code within it?

If it isn't obvious I am very new to python so please be descriptive with your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.so files are native shared libraries. They are written in C rather than Python. If you're curious about them, you can look at [Python's source code](https://github.com/python/cpython).

Comment: Is there any way to view them? I just learned about modules today. I was under the impression that modules were a collection of functions that you could import rather than re-write every time you want to use them. Given that understanding I expected I would be able to read them as .py files and see how they perform their actions.

Comment: Most modules are like that, but for performance reasons, some Python modules are written in C instead. For example, https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5e65cd39dfe73891b16d9c771892e1bc282c1eb9/Modules/mathmodule.c is the source of Python's math module.

Comment: Thank you. So what I am viewing from that link is written in C? (Is that C short for C++?)

Comment: Yes, those are written in C. No, it's not short for C++.

Comment: Thank you for your help.